# Can we insert custom Intrinsic at the start of function via LLVM Function Pass?

Tags: clang, llvm

I have added a new Intrinsic to RISCV Backend. Now I am planning to implement a Pass to insert the custom Intrinsic at the start of every function, as the first instruction, in-accordance with a command line argument which specifies the list of functions to be omitted. Is it possible to implement this as a normal FunctionPass called via *opt* tool? Or, should I call use the MachineFunctionPass?

Also, if I have to use the MachineFunctionPass, is it possible to automatically enable that pass from Clang command line, similar to how the normal *opt* based Target-Independent passes are enabled via *-Xclang -load* ?

Please guide me in this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use a normal function pass.

Comment: @arnt
Please clarify this: I expect the Intrinsic to be present as first instruction in function, i.e. even before the Prologue which changes stack/frame pointers. Is this possible via normal Function Pass?

Comment: I think you might want to work through [the LLVM tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html). It walks you through writing a simple frontend, and along the way you gather some practical experience with IR, enough to know that there generally aren't any function prologues in IR.